# Convert Base64 string to an image file return an invalid image after saving to the server

Tags: php, html5-canvas

I tried to convert base64 string to an png image, after saving to the server when i opened it, it shows an error which says 'Fatal error reading PNG image file: Decompression error in IDAT'.

Here the **base64 data** :

```
data:image/png;base64,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[…]
```

Here the **php code** :

```
$f = $handler->sanitizer($_POST['file']);
$file = $handler->sanitizer($_POST['files']);
$desc = $handler->sanitizer($_POST['desc']);
$d = $handler->sanitizer($_POST['tm']);
$status = 'Sorry something went wrong please try again';
$file_data = '';
$data = $file;

if(!empty($f) && !empty($file)){
    /**
     * file to be saved
     */
    $dir = "../users/$un/profiles/";

    $file = explode(";base64,", $file);
    $type_aux = explode("image/", $file[0]);
    $type = $type_aux[1];
    $filename =  "fr".substr(sha1(microtime()),0,20).'.'.$type;


    $new_file = $dir.$filename;

    /**
     * saving and decoding file
     */
    $upload = file_put_contents($new_file,
        base64_decode(preg_replace("#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i", '', $data)));

    if($upload){
        chmod($new_file,0777);
        $status = 'changed';
        $file_data = str_replace('..','',$filename);

        $f = explode('/',$f);
        $f = end($f);
        $path = "../users/$un/profiles/$f";
        $handler->Delete($path);
    }

}


echo json_encode(array('status'=>$status,'file'=>$file_data));
```

Comment: The base64 string you've posted is incomplete. `[...]` isn't valid base64

Comment: @glennsl base64 data that i posted above i copied it from the web console so that [...] indicate the data continue also when i return that data to view it as base64 in the image it works perfect.

Comment: Then why include it at all, and not just say that? Please also see [mcve]

Comment: @glennsl  sorry that is what i sought might fix my problem, plz if you have a way around that will be great help

Comment: I don't, I'm just trying to help you formulate a question that's possible to answer, and that might be of use to others in the future.

Comment: @glennsl thank you very much for your time,I solved it with little understating the data that returned from the server. when i replaced the base64, i found out that there is space between characters and had to concatenate them. i will update the answer bellow.

Comment: I'd recommend you to remove this question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing any space found after replacing the base64, with **+ sign**

str_replace(" ", "+", $data);

Here's the update php code

```
$f = $handler->sanitizer($_POST['file']);
$file = $handler->sanitizer($_POST['files']);
$desc = $handler->sanitizer($_POST['desc']);
$d = $handler->sanitizer($_POST['tm']);
$status = 'Sorry something went wrong please try again';
$file_data = '';
$data = $file;

if(!empty($f) && !empty($file)){
    /**
     * file to be saved
     */
    $dir = "../users/$un/profiles/";

    $file = explode(";base64,", $file);
    $type_aux = explode("image/", $file[0]);
    $type = $type_aux[1];
    $filename =  "fr".substr(sha1(microtime()),0,20).'.'.$type;


    $new_file = $dir.$filename;
    $data = preg_replace("#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i", '', $data);

    /**
     * Replace the space found in the data with + sign to work
     */

    $data = str_replace(' ','+',$data);


    /**
     * saving and decoding file
     */
    $upload = file_put_contents($new_file,
        base64_decode($data));

    if($upload){
        chmod($new_file,0777);
        $status = 'changed';
        $file_data = str_replace('..','',$filename);

        $f = explode('/',$f);
        $f = end($f);
        $path = "../users/$un/profiles/$f";
        $handler->Delete($path);
    }

}


echo json_encode(array('status'=>$status,'file'=>$file_data));
```